# incorrect whatsapp time on lumia 535 dual sim

Tags: whatsapp

I'm using Microsoft Lumia 535 dual sim and whenever i want to open my whatsapp it says my date and time is incorrect so i should change my phone's clock from settings and restart my WhatsApp. I have done that for more than 8 times, I updated it, reinstalled it and it won't work. **Please** i need help **urgently**.

Comment: Is the time zone/regional settings correct on your phone as well?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have checked time and Zone, still no luck